# Is Visual Studio missing documentation for ASP.NET MVC RC2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm checking out ASP.NET MVC RC2.  Is the API documentation completely missing?  I should be able to find something by hitting F1, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I've been developing with ASP.NET MVC for about a year, I haven't seen any *formal* documentation personally.  The best kind of documentation you are going to find is in screencasts and blogs.  Check out [Stephen Walther's MVC blog,](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/default.aspx) [Rob Conery's MVC Storefront project/adventure](http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/mvc-storefront-part-1/), and, of course, http://asp.net/mvc.  There's also a [very promising book](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-ASP-NET-MVC-1-0.productCd-0470384611.html) coming out.

I don't think you're going to find any kind of reference book or MSDN docs at this point.  You'll probably have to wait for RTM.

Comment: It looks like the RTM version doesn't come with documentation either.  I'm aware of blogs and rough drafts of books, but it would be nice to see something MVC-related when I hit F1.  Thanks for your answer -- now I know I wasn't doing something wrong.

Comment: At least the RTM comes with method/property-level documentation with intellisense.  That's really all you need most of the time.